# Find smallest value in a rolling window partitioned by group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe containing different geographical positions as well as the distance to some other places. My problem is that I want to find the closest *n* places for each geographical position. My first idea was to use `groupBy()` followed by some sort of aggregation but I couldn't get that to work.

Instead I tried to first convert the dataframe to an `RDD` and the use `groupByKey()`, it works, but the method is cumbersome. Is there is any better alternative to solve this problem? Maybe using `groupBy()` and aggregate somehow?

A small example of my approach where `n=2` with input:

```
+---+--------+
| id|distance|
+---+--------+
|  1|     5.0|
|  1|     3.0|
|  1|     7.0|
|  1|     4.0|
|  2|     1.0|
|  2|     3.0|
|  2|     3.0|
|  2|     7.0|
+---+--------+
```

Code:

```
df.rdd.map{case Row(id: Long, distance: Double) => (id, distance)}
  .groupByKey()
  .map{case (id: Long, iter: Iterable[Double]) => (id, iter.toSeq.sorted.take(2))}
  .toDF("id", "distance")
  .withColumn("distance", explode($"distance"))
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+
| id|distance|
+---+--------+
|  1|     3.0|
|  1|     4.0|
|  2|     1.0|
|  2|     3.0|
+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Window as below:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
case class A(id: Long, distance: Double)
val df = List(A(1, 5.0), A(1,3.0), A(1, 7.0), A(1, 4.0), A(2, 1.0), A(2, 3.0), A(2, 4.0), A(2, 7.0))
  .toDF("id", "distance")

val window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("distance")  
val result = df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window)).where(col("rank") <= 2 )

result.drop("rank").show()
```

You can increase the number of result you want by replacing the 2.

Hope this helps.